# Manipulating Popups using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, popup, arcgis-pro

I am using the ArcPy libary at the moment to manipulate data in layers.

It looks like ArcGIS Pro allows the user to use popups for each layer which allows selected data to be displayed in a popup once clicked.

I cannot find a way to access this feature with ArcPy.

ArcPy seems to be able to mimic most of ArcGIS Desktop functionality, but I cannot find a method or object to directly configure popups for each layer.

I am attempting to display charts on a given point once clicked on.

Answer (score 3):

I submitted this as an idea and apparently it can be done in ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro using the Cartographic Information Model:
https://community.esri.com/t5/python-ideas/ability-to-access-the-popup-object-in-arcpy-arcgis-pro/idc-p/1042108#M32

The code snippet provided was as follows:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
m = p.listMaps('Map')[0]
l = m.listLayers('GreatLakes')[0]
l_cim = l.getDefinition('V2')
l_cim.showPopups = True
l.setDefinition(l_cim)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen anywhere that ArcPy can access the popup functionality of ArcGIS Pro.

ArcPy only makes a subset of ArcGIS Pro SDK functionality available and most of that is related to Geoprocessing and Mapping.

If it is important for you to have this functionality added to ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro then I would recommend submitting an [ArcGIS Idea](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).

There is an existing ArcGIS Idea to be able to [Programmatically access HTML Popup in Layer Properties](https://community.esri.com/ideas/9785) but this relates to ArcMap and not ArcGIS Pro.